# Error in Release mode but not in Build mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, opencv

I recently made a project using opencv and c++ in visual 2008
When i build the project in Debug mode - i don't face any issues - but when i build it in release mode i get the following errors:

```
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvHaarDetectObjects
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvCvtColor
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvCreateImage
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvDestroyWindow
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvWaitKey
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvGetSize
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvReleaseCapture
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvCreateMemStorage
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvClone
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvNamedWindow
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvQueryFrame
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvLoad
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvRectangle
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvCreateCameraCapture
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvGetSeqElem
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _cvShowImage
```

Comment: How big did you allow this project to get before you tried building in the release mode?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies settings in the Release configuration ; you have undoubtedly forgotten to include the OpenCV libraries. Just copy-paste them from the Debug configuration, but don't forget to remove the `d` suffix.

E.g. `cv210.lib` : Release mode and `cv210d.lib` : Debug mode.

Answer (score 3):

You are not including the same libraries in your release build that you include in your debug build. "unresolved external symbol" means it cannot find the implementation for a function you are referencing.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you give Additional Dependencies to Debug mode but not in Release.